# How to login a website using httpwebrequest via my web app or generic handler and access the content?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

Basically I am making a chat app for my university students only and for that I have to make sure they are genuine by checking there details on UMS(university management system) and get their basic detail so they chat genuinely. I am nearly done with my chat app only the login is left.

So I want to login to my UMS page via my website from a generic handler.
and then navigate to another page in it to access there basic info keeping the session alive.

I did research on httpwebrequest and failed to login with my credentials.

https://ums.lpu.in/lpuums
(made in asp.net)

I did tried codes from other posts for login.

I am novice to this part so bear with me.. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Scrap(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string Url1 = "https://www.example.com";//first url
        string Url2 = "https://www.example.com/login.aspx";//secret url to post request to

        //first request
        CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url1);
        request1.CookieContainer = jar;
        //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
        HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();

        //second request
        string postData = "***viewstate here***";//VIEWSTATE
        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url2);
        request2.CookieContainer = jar;
        request2.KeepAlive = true;
        request2.Referer = Url2;
        request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request2.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request2.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request2.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request2.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream newStream = request2.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return responseData;
    }
```

This is the code which works for me any one can add there links and viewstate for asp.net websites to scrap and you need to take care of cookie too.
and for other websites(non asp.net) they don't require viewstate.
Use fiddler to find things needed to add in header and viewstate or cookie.
Hope this helps if some one having the problem. :)

Comment: thank you @CodetrixStudio , but i want to ask a question, what if i want to check if the user is already logged-in or not, and if yes, skip to login process and go to request3, thank you.

Comment: @Aura simply search for a string in your response that only exists in a logged in page, if it doesn't exist that means user is not logged in. Pretty generic though as I don't know your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual handshake with UMS via a defined API, you would end up scraping UMS html, which is bad for various reasons.

I would suggest you read up on [Single Sign On (SSO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).

A few articles on SSO and ASP.NET -
1. [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms)
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd577079.aspx)
3. [asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1139783.aspx/1)

**Edit 1**

Although, I think this is a bad idea, since you say you are out of options, [here](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.in/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html) is a link that shows how [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) can help in scraping the web pages.

Beware of the drawbacks of screen scraping, changes from UMS will not be communicated to you, and you will see your application not working all of a sudden.

Comment: if I understood correct then SSO must be enabled in UMS to use it, but UMS is still in beta and they don't provide any api or any other similar thing. I only have the option to scrap the info I need by navigating to that page..

Comment: @ParveenKhatkar - I've edited my answer to include screen scraping reference.